# Press any key to MOK management

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
When I turn on the machine it comes a blue screen and it reads

> Press any key to MOK management

Then, before I do anything, it comes my account login window and I login using my name and pass.

What is it about?